# how can i get all the dropdown values in a list

Tags: selenium, webdriver, javascript

I want all the options which are there in a dropdown .I am using selenium + javascript to write the testcases 
Please let me know how to get all the options from the dropdown

i know in java we can achive this by using Select class and getOptions() , i need the same how to achive this when we are using webdriverjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone develop a webdriverjs-helper:

- https://github.com/surevine/webdriverjs-helper

This helper provide a function to get the values of a dropdown:

- `browser.dropdownlist(selector).value(valueHandler)`
- https://github.com/surevine/webdriverjs-helper#browserdropdownlistselectorvaluesvalueshandler

Comment: Hi ,
 Thanks for your answer
here what is selector ?

Comment: @sunilkumar Selector is another term for Locator. List of selectors: CSS ID, CSS class name, HTML tag name, XPath, link text etc.